# Paging Dynamic Asp.net Table

Tags: asp.net, pagination

I need your help on creating paging for Dynamic ASP.net table. is it possible?. can someone help me? below code created a table and later i am binding results of 10000+ rows.

```
Table tbl = new Table();

    tbl.ID = "Table1";
    tbl.CellSpacing = 1;

    PanelReport.Controls.Add(tbl);
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the `Table` to do that.
It is meant for designing simple layouts.

[Databound controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc295567.aspx) like [GridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479339.aspx) which offer inbuilt Pagination would suit your needs better.